# Ubuntu 18.04 Nvidia update failed?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, graphics, 18.04

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. After the upgrade, I did the usual `sudo apt-get update` to be sure that I will have the latest updates. But when I tried to update my Nvidia drivers, I tried to detect the recommended one with:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and as usual, I got the recommended drivers and the graphics card model:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:04:00.0 == modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001299sv00001043sd0000105Ebc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GK208BM [GeForce 920M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

So when I input the command:

sudo apt install nvidia-390

After reading the package, building etc., I got this message:

```
Package nvidia-390 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it: 
 libnvidia-gl-390
 nvidia-kernel-source-390:i386 
 nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390:i386
 libnvidia-gl-390:i386
 nvidia-kernel-source-390
 nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390
E: Package 'nvidia-390' has no installation candidate
```

I know it says that is replaced but I observe some "pixel spikes" when I move a window. So did it fail. Should I do something else in order to update the drivers?

Comment: My Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS is using nVidia `384.130`. After upgrade to 18.04 I notice `390` drivers were being installed and when rebooting nVidia wasn't even being used but rather Intel iGPU HD 530 instead. Because I only upgrade to test the upgrading process on a cloned partition I didn't really investigate. The next time I boot the 18.04 partition though I think I'll install the 384.130 drivers which seem to work fine in Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS under kernel 4.13.0-36. Using kernel 4.15.0-29 has suspend/resume loop--It won't suspend.

Comment: In 18.04 the NVIDIA driver name is `nvidia-driver-390` by default.   If you setup the `graphics-drivers` ppa you can install `nvidia-driver-396`.

Comment: @Terrance thank you for the advice that solved my problem. I have the newest version, so thank you again :)

Comment: @karel thank you too I read the recommended link that you posted and it is similar with the Terrance's answer. Thank you though!! :)